# Change the way CakePHP associate models

Tags: json, cakephp, restkit

I'm trying to split out some JSON strings in order to be parsed by this [RestKit](http://restkit.org/)'s iPhone library, but CakePHP is splitting out an incompatible string. For example, the string below is what it's currently splitting out:

```
1. {"Question":{"id":"1","content":"Test","player_id":"1","points":"0","votes":"0","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"Player":{"id":"1","username":"player_test"}}
```

I need to have something like:

```
2. {"Question":{"id":"1","content":"Test","player_id":"1","points":"0","votes":"0","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Player":{"id":"1","username":"player_test"}}}
```

Note that the Player response should be part of Question.

The way the models are setup on Cake is that `'Question' belongs to 'Player'` which the latter `hasMany 'Question'`

I am looking for the proper way of telling Cake to output something like the response #2 above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterFind()` callback of your Question model to nest the Player record inside the Question record. Or modify the results array as required after fetching. The various function of [Hash](http://api.cakephp.org/class/hash) class might help you in reformatting the array.

Comment: Be very careful doing this. Adding code to the afterFind() callback will cause the result of all queries performed with that Model to be altered. This might not be what you want. I'll post an alternative

Comment: You are correct. I should have probably added that disclaimer in my comment.

Comment: no problem, afterFind() *can* be the place to do it, just trying to prevent less experienced CakePHP users to mess up their application because they don't know what it's doing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom method to your Question model that returns the result in the desired format. This will keep your code clean and keep the data-processing/formatting logic in your Model (where it should be in most cases);

For example, inside your Question model:

```
public function getQuestionsForPlayer($playerId)
{
    $results = $this->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(/* fields */),
        'conditions' => array(/* ..... */
        /* etc */
    ));

    // Process your result to be in the right format
    // Hash::extract() and other Hash:: methods
    // may be helpful here as @ADmad mentioned

    return $processedResult;
}
```

As ADmad mentioned, the Hash utility may be helpful. Documentation is located here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html